# cannot create more than 2 instances with devstack

Tags: devstack

I am hosting devstack locally at my home and i need some help in figuring out why i cannot add more instances.

So far, I imported the ubuntu iso as an image and have created 2 instances (5GB each).
The problem is I am unable to create any more instance with volume. Whenever I create instance with volume i get error saying

```
Unable to get log for instance "
```

If I delete one of the instances that i have created then i can re-create a new instance with 5GB size (and only upto a GB more). I am unable to create any more instance however after that.

There seems to be a limit when creating instances with volumes. It says the "Default Quotas" is 10GB for the volumns. Is there a way to increase that?

Answer (score 1):

10 volumes does not mean 10GB but number of volumes.
You can change Cinder quota in dashboard.

In juno, Identity > Projects > Modifi Quotas (in actions)

In Icehouse "Identity" is under the System Panel.